# Is $1-e^{-|x-y|}\leq |x-y|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I have just seen a proof where they use this inequality, but I can’t figure out why is this true. I know that $e^x>x \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ But I can’t get to this expression

Comment: $1+x\leq e^x$ for all real $x$

Comment: First, just replace $|x-y|$ by a variable $z\geq0,$ this asks if $e^{-z}\geq 1-z.$

Comment: Hello, how can I prove that $1+x\leq e^x$

Comment: It isn't 100% obvious that $e^{-z}\geq 1-z,$ but it is obvious if $z\geq 1,$ and if $0\leq z<1,$ then $$e^{-z}=1-z+z^2/2-z^3/3!+\cdots$$ is an alternating decreasing sequence, and so we get $1-z\leq e^{-z}.$

Comment: You can differentiate $f(x)=e^x-x-1$, use taylor expansion of $e^{x}$, etc..

Comment: Or, for $0\leq z<1,$ this is equivalent to: $e^{z}\leq \frac1{1-z},$ which we can see just by comparing the power series.

Comment: Another way to prove $e^w\geq 1+w$ for all real $w$ is to use Bernoulli's inequality, which states that if $u\geq -1$ and $n$ is a positive integer, then $(1+u)^n\geq 1+nu.$ Then use that: $(1+w/n)^n\to e^w,$ and, for large $n,$ $w/n\geq -1,$ so $(1+w/n)^n\geq 1+w.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $h:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ , $h(x)=e^x-1-x$ then $h’(x)=e^x-1 \geq 0$ so h is increasing. Even more, $h(x)\geq h(0)=0$
So if $x\geq 0$, then $h(x)\geq 0\Rightarrow e^x\geq 1+x$

Comment: You've only proven $e^x\geq 1+x$ for $x\geq0,$ but we specifically need it proven for $x<0.$

Comment: You can adjust this proof by showing that $h'(x)$ means $h$ is decreasing for $x<0$ and increasing after, so $h(0)=0$ is the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Since the exponential is a convex function, it is above its tangent at $x=0$, that is
$$
e^x \geq 1 + x
$$